# Exclude Dependency while package War file

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am using the spring boot application and would like to exclude some dependencies while generating package. These package should not be included in generated war file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Please show the full pom file because provided dependencies should not being packaged into the resulting war file...the other question is why are you using war instead of the usual way `jar` for spring boot application?

Comment: In my case I should generating WAR file. I don't need to export these particular dependency. But these dependency i am using in development mode only.

Answer (score 0):

1. For exclusions of specific files from the generated war file, include the list of dependencies in `<packagingExcludes>` of build plugin, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html. This lets you remove specific files from the generated war file.
2. For dependencies available only during build and test phase, make use of `provided` scope, https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-dependency-scopes/
3. If you are looking at excluding transitive dependencies, you can include a section for ****exclusions****  within the dependency, https://www.educba.com/maven-exclude-dependency/

Comment: No I want to remove or exclude complete dependency during war file generation.

Comment: Please check if this helps you: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.htm

Comment: link is expired.

Comment: @balias provided dependencies are not being packaged by maven-war-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) so to define them as packagingExclude is not necessary nor a good idea...